# How do I replace a function by a mock implementation when unit-testing a shared library?

Tags: c, macos, unit-testing, mocking, dynamic-linking

I am having the opposite problem that [Can you compile a shared object to prefer local symbols even if it's being loaded by a program compiled with -rdynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477163/can-you-compile-a-shared-object-to-prefer-local-symbols-even-if-its-being-loade) is solving.

Using the naming from the linked question, I have a dynamic library where `baz` calls `bar`, and I have a test binary exercising the library, which substitutes its own fake implementation of `bar` for test purposes. This works fine on Linux, because `-rdynamic` is used to link.

The source of the test is https://github.com/apache/qpid-dispatch/blob/b172f501028b36d786b4c83bcee1e195cd17fcf2/tests/timer_test.c. The functions being mocked are, among others `qd_server_timeout` and `qd_timer_now` (that is the inlined one, see comments).

I am at a loss how to achieve the same on macOS. What are the correct linker options there?

Comment: Maybe I have it. I tried various likely options from `man ld`, and when I gave to CMake this, the test passed `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-export_dynamic,-flat_namespace" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-export_dynamic,-flat_namespace"`

Comment: The above is not enough, I had to also add `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fno-inline"`. That passes the test, but is obviously a no-go patch for the project. We do want inlining for performance... Seems to me that the mocking strategy will need to be reevaluated.

Answer (score 0):

For now, it is [resolved](https://github.com/apache/qpid-dispatch/pull/590) by adding `__attribute__((noinline))` to `bar` ([commit](https://github.com/apache/qpid-dispatch/commit/f81b834769d9426679183b498a7b3e0162bc8fed)), and linking with `-Wl,-flat_namespace` ([commit](https://github.com/apache/qpid-dispatch/commit/1c7203b2518e343bb4c5d774a2a7179555ef2793)). The `-export_dynamic` was actually not needed.

I am still looking for alternative solutions.